# How to use secure encryption of an existing column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, encryption-asymmetric, encryption-symmetric

I want to encrypt an existing column in SQL Server 2005, using an UPDATE statement, moving the old content into the new encrypted column.

So I have 2 choices: Symmetric and Asymmetric.

The issue I have is that with a symmetric key, I have to embed the password into an SP in order to read the column like:

```
-- Create key (at some earlier point)
create symmetric key sk_user_profile with algorithm = aes_192 encryption by password = 'P@ssword!!';

-- Now encrypt the contents
-- open the key so that we can use it
open symmetric key sk_user_profile decryption by password = 'P@ssword!!';

UPDATE users
SET password_enc = encryptbykey(key_guid('sk_user_profile'), password_plain, 1, user_id)

close symmetric key sk_user_profile
```

Now if I want to select the data, I still have to re-open the key with

```
open symmetric key sk_user_profile decryption by password = 'P@ssword!!';
```

Which is defeating the point isn't it, as I am embedding a plain-text password within a stored procedure.

Some questions

1. Is there any way around this - i.e. creating a certificate with this password and then referring to the certificate instead?
2. Would this certificate have to be purchased (like SSL), or can I create my own?
3. Is this method scalable across fail-over clustered databases, i.e. the encryption is not based on the machine, only the password provided. Therefore failover can still read the passwords

Thanks for your help

Comment: There is encryption by certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is this:

```
create certificate MyEncryptionCertificate with subject = 'MyCertificate'

create symmetric key MySymmetricKey with algorithm = aes_256 encryption by certificate MyEncryptionCertificate
```

And then:

```
open symmetric key MySymmetricKey decryption by certificate MyEncryptionCertificate

select encryptbykey(key_guid('MySymmetricKey'), 'tada')) EncryptedMessage
```

I hope this blog will help you along the way.

[SQL SERVER – Introduction to SQL Server Encryption and Symmetric Key Encryption Tutorial with Script](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/)

And also this blog entry, which deals specifically with certificates in a failover environment.

[Solution Using Certificates Authentication on Production Servers](http://blog.shakeeluddin.com/sql-2005-database-mirroring-with-failover-tutorial/)

Comment: Pinal Dave!! Why didn't I think of that! I was hoping there was a way to generate the certificate from a password. However, will this work across a clustered environments. So Web -> Failover Cluster -> (DB1/DB2)